# Time picker how to reload its view?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi i am writing an app which uses the time picker element which function is to choose a "start hour" and "end hour". Here is how i pass from choosing "start hour" to "end hour" using these two simple functions.

```
public void Forward(View view){
    TimePicker zalaczenie = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

    String godzina = String.valueOf(zalaczenie.getCurrentHour());
    String minuta = String.valueOf(zalaczenie.getCurrentMinute());
    Button zapisz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    zapisz.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Button forward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    forward.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    TextView labelka = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    labelka.setText("Godzina wyłączenia");
    int godzinka = Integer.parseInt(godzina);
    if(godzinka<10){godzina = "0"+godzina;}
    int minutka = Integer.parseInt(minuta);
    if(minutka<10){minuta = "0"+minuta;}
    String OnTimeSet = godzina + minuta + "00";
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),OnTimeSet, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}

public void Save(View view){
    TimePicker wylaczenie = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

    String godzina = String.valueOf(wylaczenie.getCurrentHour());
    String minuta = String.valueOf(wylaczenie.getCurrentMinute());
    int godzinka = Integer.parseInt(godzina);
    if(godzinka<10){godzina = "0"+godzina;}
    int minutka = Integer.parseInt(minuta);
    if(minutka<10){minuta = "0"+minuta;}
    String OffTimeSet = godzina + minuta + "00";
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),OffTimeSet, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

}
```

My problem is that if i choose the time of "start hour" and then pass to choosing "end hour" the time picker element does not starts with hour to choose but with minutes as they were picked in the "start hour" picking. So my question is how do i reload the time picker element so if i want to pick another variable time it starts from picking hours?

Comment: Use `TimePicker.setCurrentHour(...);` and `TimePicker.setCurrentMinute(...);` to reset your `TimePicker` at the end of your methods.

Comment: Nope that is still cousing the time picker to be focused on choosing minutes after setting hour and minute value

Comment: If you want to remove the focus, use `TimePicker.clearFocus()` for that.

Comment: .clearFocus doesn't work either what i want to reach, is to after pressing the Forward button, the first value which will be used should be hours not minutes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the point. It's hard to understand what you are talking about. Can you post an image to show whats your actual result and what you expect to have?

Comment: There is no need of picture the forward method is called exactly when the forward button is pressed.

Comment: @vincenzo how did you refresh then your hour and minute view to initialized state. I mean how did you reset your time picker view programatically?